# Is it possible to add my Mobile app as an iframe on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, mobile

I created a Mobile app using (https://www.greencopper.com/solutions).
It has a cross-platform which I can edith the contains online and would like to add it to my Website (Like facebook iframe "scrollable").

Comment: Your app is hibrit or native ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I created the app using (greencopper.com).
I'm searching for defination (difference :) )

Comment: Which technology is your mobile app written ? Native Android or ionic or react native vs..

Comment: @pc_coder I couldn't find out what kind it is. I created it using www.greencopper.com and it has a cross-platform which I can edith the contains online. you may find it out using this link: https://www.greencopper.com/solutions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your app is a [Progressive Web App](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_application), yes: just use your app's URL as `src` attribute of the `iframe` and you should achieve your desired result.

If your app is a native app (i.e. you have a file which should be loaded in the phone, probably through the stores), no you can't.

Comment: This is an Android and IOS Application, how to get a link from it?

Comment: Sorry @hamid but "This is an Android and IOS Application" means everything and nothig. The point it how do you install it on the phone. If it is a PWA you know the URL. If you don't know the URL it seems to be a native app (installed through the stores): there is no link and the answer is simply "you can't do that".

Comment: Thank you helping me not to search for a solution in vain.